# Why applying a conditional expression doesn't work on numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I can't figure out why my `relu` function doesn't work but `squarer` works, how is it different?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

squarer = lambda x: x ** 2
squarer(x)
# array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25])

relu = lambda x : 0 if x <= 0 else x
relu(x)
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the value of `x <= 0`?

Comment: The reason "squarer" works is that the ** operator automatically maps over its LHS (and maybe RHS, two).   The "0 if x..." expression does not, so x is taken to be an array, and you get your error.

Comment: To write an `if` test in vectorized form, you could use `np.where`: `relu = lambda x : np.where(x <= 0, 0, x)`

Comment: @hpaulj I thought when applying `relu` or `square` to `np.array`, python will iterate over each element and apply the lambda function

Comment: @JohanC thanks that works, I'm wondering if it's more performant than `np.array([relu(a) for a in x])`?

Comment: @MarkLavin thanks for the explanation, it seems I misinterpreted the semantic

Comment: @Raftel `np.where` is vectorized, while `[relu(a) for a in x]` goes one by one and has the overhead of creating a Python list. Especially for larger arrays, `np.where` is much faster.

Comment: Python (the interpreter) does not iterate.  It's the numpy methods and operators that do that.  If `x` is an array, then `x**2` uses the arrays `power` method.  `x<=0` returns a boolean array, the same shape as `x`.  `if/else` is a python scalar operation.

Comment: @JohanC, it's worth keeping in mind that `where` is not an `iterator` either; it's a function.  The 3 arguments are evaluated in full (including the `x<=0`).  The `where` then does an elementwise assignment.  I've had to correct a number of users (especially `pandas`) who think it conditionally evaluates the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [6]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   ...: 
   ...: squarer = lambda x: x ** 2
   ...: squarer(x)
Out[6]: array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25])
```

The `lambda` is just a function definition, and is equivalent of doing:

```
In [7]: x**2
Out[7]: array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25])
```

The function layer doesn't add any iteration.  It's the `power` method of the `x` array that's doing the elementwise iteration.

```
In [8]: relu = lambda x : 0 if x <= 0 else x
```

Similarly the `relu` does not add any iteration; it's scalar python `if/else` clause.

```
In [13]: x = np.arange(-3,4)
In [14]: x
Out[14]: array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])
```

It can be applied to elements of `x` with a list comprehension:

```
In [15]: [relu(i) for i in x]
Out[15]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Arrays have a `lt` method, so:

```
In [16]: x<=0
Out[16]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False])
```

It can be use in `masked` way:

```
In [17]: x1=x.copy()
In [18]: x1[x<=0] = 0
In [19]: x
Out[19]: array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])
In [20]: x1
Out[20]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Or via a `where`:

```
In [22]: np.where(x<=0, 0,x)
Out[22]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

`where` isn't an iterator either.  It is effectively the same thing as the [17][18] lines.

Using an array in a `if` expression amounts to trying to convert it to a scalar boolean:

```
In [24]: if x<=0:x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-24-6cecebf070dc>", line 1, in <module>
    if x<=0:x
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [25]: bool(x<=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-25-f1a519ed746f>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(x<=0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It works it the array has only one element, but otherwise it raises this ambiguity error:

```
In [26]: bool(np.array(1)<=0)
Out[26]: False
```

but for "empty" array:

```
In [28]: bool(np.array([])<=0)
<ipython-input-28-03e1626841fc>:1: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  bool(np.array([])<=0)
Out[28]: False
```

But testing for a 'empty' list is ok:

```
In [29]: bool([])
Out[29]: False
```